# I couldn't show php exception message in the stdout

Tags: php

I'm debugging a script that we run in `CLI` because it's not working right.
I found the line that doesn't work

```
$connection = $this->em->getConnection();
....
$connection->executeUpdate('TRUNCATE table');
$connection->executeUpdate('TRUNCATE another_table');
// Below is the line that raises an exception silently
$connection->executeUpdate('TRUNCATE fos_fos_user');
```

When I run the script as is I don't get any error or warning or anything that says script's failed. It just stops.

I added `error_reporting` and `display_errors` as following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // tried with -1 as well
ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout');

$connection = $this->em->getConnection();
....
$connection->executeUpdate('TRUNCATE table');
$connection->executeUpdate('TRUNCATE another_table');
// Below is the line that raises an exception silently
$connection->executeUpdate('TRUNCATE fos_fos_user');
```

But the output does not change...

> php --version: PHP 5.5.20 (cli)

How do I display messages sent by php (errors, notices, warnings or whatever) ?

Comment: You did not actually misspell it `dispaly_errors` ... right?

Comment: @CBroe I updated my question